# Can't put a horizontal scroll on my TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form in which there is a TableLayoutPanel in which there are several RadioButtons.
The form has a fixed size and the controls are dynamically generated.

Sometimes, the text of the RadioButtons is too long to be entirely displayed and I'd like to enable a horizontal scroll to the TableLayout in this case. But no matter how I tried, I can't figure out how to do it. Simply setting the TableLayoutPanel Autoscroll property to true did nothing.

I've tried to nest the TableLayout inside a Panel, but it didn't work. I've tried to put each RadioButton inside a Panel, then put the Panel inside the TableLayout. This made the horizontal scroll appear but of course the RadioButtons weren't in the same container any more so they were independant from each other. I've messed with several properties of the controls but to no avail.

I really have no idea what to do.
Here is how the controls are generated (this is the original code, prior to my modifications) :

```
public static Panel ChoicePanel(string title, string description, string internalName, bool radio, string oldValue, List<string> choices, int num, bool required)
    {
        var nbrow = (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(description) ? 1 : 2);
        var nbcol = 1; var currentRow = realFirstRow;
        if (radio) nbrow += choices.Count();
        else nbrow += 1;

        var panel = GeneratePanel(title, nbcol, nbrow, num, required);

            foreach (var ch in choices)
            {
                var rb = new RadioButton()
                {
                    Name = "rb" + internalName + currentRow,
                    Text = ch,
                    Checked = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldValue) && ch == oldValue,
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                    AutoCheck = true,
                };
                panel.Controls.Add(rb, firstCol, currentRow);
                currentRow++;
            }

        AddDescription(description, currentRow, panel);
        return panel;
    }

private static TableLayoutPanel GeneratePanel(string title, int numcol, int numlines, int num, bool required)
    {
        var panel = new TableLayoutPanel()
        {
            AutoSize = true,
            AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly,
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            ColumnCount = numcol + 1,
            RowCount = numlines,
            Name = "panel" + num,
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < numlines; i++)
        {
            panel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        }
        ((Panel)panel).Margin = new Padding(5, 10, 10, 5);
        var lTitle = GenerateTitle(title, required);
        panel.Controls.Add(lTitle, 1, 0);
        panel.SetColumnSpan(lTitle, numcol);
        var labColor = new Label()
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            BackColor = notErrorColor,
            Name = "lbColor",
        };
        panel.Controls.Add(labColor, 0, 0);
        panel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 10));
        panel.SetRowSpan(labColor, numlines);
        return panel;
    }
```

Please note that it was someone else who wrote this code, but I will try to answer questions as best as I can.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It doesn't look right.  Note how the code is giving conflicting layout instructions.  AutoSize = true cannot match DockStyle.Fill.  The latter wins and the TLP size is set by the form size.  AutoScroll = true is required to let it display a scrollbar.  The radiobuttons problem is murky, using DockStyle.Fill cannot be correct.  Consider trying this out in the designer first, the instant WYSIWYG feedback is helpful.

Comment: Thanks, a lot! The form is actually much more complex, the table layout is inside a panel which is inside another tablelayout and all of their properties are set as the example above. I didn't trully know about Dock and AutoSize properties. I set the TLP's Dock prop to false, added a bottom padding (I don't want the vertical scrollbar to show), I disabled Dock on the radiobtn as well and set its Autosize to true and it worked. Thanks again, I'm a beginner, working alone on this app that I didn't make and I'm having a hard time maintaining it :)